# I am trying to retrieve images, which are stored by their url in a php file.They are stored in a folder called images

Tags: javascript, php, json

So far i have this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
    $.get("museums.php",function(data,status){
    var response='';
    //console.log(data);
    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
    museums = json.museums;
    for(let m in museums) { $("#names-list").append("<p>" + museums[m].museum_name) 
    + $("#desc-list").append("<p>" + museums[m].museum_description )
    + $("#address-list").append("<p>" + museums[m].address )
    + $("#type-list").append("<p>"+ museums[m].museum_type )
    + $("#list").append("<p>"+ museums[m].postcode )
    + $("#list").append("<p>"+ museums[m].website )
    + $("#list").append("<p>"+ museums[m].opening_hours )
    + $("#list").append("<p>"+ museums[m].closed_days )
    + $("#list").append("<p>"+ museums[m].distance_citycentre )
    //+ $("#list").append('<img src="/images/' + museums[m].images + ‘/>’”)


 }
```

A function is run when a museum is selected.

```
function loadKelvin() {
    $("#content").append('<img src="/CourseworkResources/images/' +      museums[0].images + '"/>');}
```

They are to be displayed in a div called "content".
However the return is simply nothing or: [object Object][object Object][object Object]

PHP file

```
<?php
$museumsarray = array(
    array("museum_id" => "1", "museum_name" => "Kelvingrove Art Gallery and Museum", "museum_description" => "Glasgow's main art gallery and museum situated in the west end of the city.", "museum_type" => "Art Gallery",
            "address" => "Argyle Street", "postcode" => "G3 8AG", "lat" => "55.8684124", "long" => "-4.29054489999998", "website" => "http://www.glasgowlife.org.uk/museums/kelvingrove/Pages/default.aspx", 
            "distance_citycentre" => array("driving_miles"=>"2.2", "driving_minutes"=>"12", "walking_miles"=>"1.7", "walking_minutes"=>"34"),
            "opening_hours" => array("Monday"=>"10am-5pm","Tuesday"=>"10am-5pm","Wednesday"=>"10am-5pm","Thursday"=>"10am-5pm","Friday"=>"11am-5pm","Saturday"=>"10am-5pm","Sunday"=>"11am-5pm"),
            "closed_days" => array("January 1st", "January 2nd", "December 24th", "December 25th", "December 26th", "December 31st"),
            "images" => array(
                array("image_id" => "34", "description" => "Front View Of Kelvingrove", "url" => "Kelvingrove_Front_View_1 (Medium).jpg"),
                array("image_id" => "35", "description" => "Front View Of Kelvingrove", "url" => "Kelvingrove_Front_View_2 (Medium).jpg"),  
                array("image_id" => "36", "description" => "Front View Of Kelvingrove", "url" => "Kelvingrove_Front_View_3 (Medium).jpg"),  
                array("image_id" => "37", "description" => "Front View Of Kelvingrove", "url" => "Kelvingrove_Front_View_4 (Medium).jpg"),              
                array("image_id" => "38", "description" => "Rear View Of Kelvingrove", "url" => "Kelvingrove_Rear_View_1 (Medium).jpg"),    
                array("image_id" => "39", "description" => "Rear View Of Kelvingrove", "url" => "Kelvingrove_Rear_View_2 (Medium).jpg"),    
                array("image_id" => "40", "description" => "Organ in Kelvingrove Art Gallery", "url" => "Organ_Kelvingrove (Medium).jpg"),
                array("image_id" => "41", "description" => "Heads Exhibit at Kelvingrove", "url" => "Heads_Kelvingrove (Medium).jpg"),          
                array("image_id" => "42", "description" => "Exhibits at Kelvingrove", "url" => "Plane_Elephant_Giraffe (Medium).jpg")   
            ),
            "keyterms" => array(1,2,4,8,12,13,16,23,26,27,29,30,31,32,33,34,36,39,40,41,43,46,49,50)
    ),
```

Function

```
function loadKelvin(){
    $("#content").append("<p>" + "<h4>"+"Museum Name "+"</h4>" +museums[0].museum_name)
    $("#content").append("<p>" + "<h4>"+"Description "+"</h4>" +museums[0].museum_description)
    $("#content").append("<p>" + "<h4>"+"Address "+"</h4>" +museums[0].address)
    $("#content").append("<p>" + "<h4>"+"Postcode "+"</h4>" + museums[0].postcode)
    $("#content").append("<p>" +  "<h4>"+"Type "+"</h4>" +museums[0].museum_type)
    $("#content").append("<p>" + "<h4>"+"Website "+"</h4>"+ "<a href>" + museums[0].website+ "</a>")
    $("#content").append("<p>" + "<h4>"+"Opening Hours "+"</h4>" + museums[0].opening_hours)
    $("#content").append("<p>" + "<h4>"+"Closed Days "+"</h4>" + museums[0].closed_days)
    $("#content").append("<p>" + "<h4>"+"Distance from City Centre "+"</h4>" + museums[0].distance_citycentre)



 }
```

Comment: Can you post the returned result of `console.log(json)`?

Comment: Please see the raw response from PHP, post it here so we can help you format it. You can view it in the development tools in your browser. Also show full code sample, not just pieces of it.

Comment: @lonut The console response:  [object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[ob…,[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object]:1 GET http://localhost/CourseworkResources/images/[object%20Object],[object%20Obj…t],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `json_encode` in PHP before sending the result to AJAX:

`json_encode($museumsarray);`

And that should solve your problem.

**Update:**

I've found your problem. You are not parsing the object correctly. You need to use a second `for in` loop. I've tested it and it works:

```
 $.get("museums.php", function(data, status) {
   var response = '';
   var json = $.parseJSON(data);
   museums = json.museums;
   for (var m in museums) {
     var imgObj = museums[m].images;
     for (var x in imgObj) {
          if(imgObj[x].url){
            $("#list").append("<img src='/images/" + imgObj[x].url + "'/>");
          }
     }
   }
 });
```

I've also removed some weird characters from this line like `’` and `”`:

`$("#list").append('<img src="/images/' + museums[m].images + ‘/>’”)`

Changed it to:

`$("#list").append("<img src='/images/" + imgObj[x].url + "'/>");`

Comment: Forgot the end code in the php, it is already encoded.  );
 echo '{"museums":';
 echo json_encode($museumsarray) . '}';
?>

Comment: Ok, then what do you get if you do a `console.log(data);`, before `var json = $.parseJSON(data);`?

Comment: The code works and it loads an "object" but it doesn't display the images I need

Comment: @II2710, I've found the problem, check my updated answer. If there's a problem please tell me.

Comment: Still only displaying [object Object]. Ive added it to my function by rather than using museum[m] i used museum[0] which is the id of the required museum. Also edited the source, to show the full $.get and the full function

Comment: @lonut Removed it.

Comment: @II2710, where do you call `loadKelvin()` function? And what's the role of it? Also, always check your console for errors and messages. And what do you mean by `A function is run when a museum is selected.`? When is a museum selected? What triggers that selection? You have the same code in the AJAX call and in that function too. It's a bit confusing without an explanation.

Comment: @lonut The names of the museums are in a drop down menu. When a museum is selected it calls the corresponding function, in this case "loadKelvin()". The console is displaying the names of the images but no errors.

Comment: Update got an error now; Kelvingrove_Front_View_1%20(Medium).jpg:1 GET http://localhost/images/Kelvingrove_Front_View_1%20(Medium).jpg 404 (Not Found) @lonut

Comment: @II2710, that's maybe because the image doesn't exist. You can use an if statement to resolve that error. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Awesome. Glad to be helping, @II2710.